# why is the output size of reduction blocks of inception resnet v2 does not match with the research paper?

Tags: inceptionresnetv2

i want to crosscheck the output size of inception and reduction blocks according to the paper of "Inception-v4, Inception-ResNet and the Impact of Residual Connections on Learning" by importing inception resnet v2 as:
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet',include_top=True)
base_model.summary()
output:
block8_10_conv (Conv2D)         (None, 8, 8, 2080)   933920      block8_10_mixed[0][0]

---

block8_10 (Lambda)              (None, 8, 8, 2080)   0           block8_9_ac[0][0]
block8_10_conv[0][0]
here 8 x 8 x 2080 is not even in the paper. why are both different?